# I cannot open Contacts in Android Emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator

When i try to open Contacts in my emulator it opens a popup window saying 
       **Sorry!**
    **The Process android android.process.acore has stopped unexpectedly Please try again**

Then it close but not open Contacts.What Should i do to open contacts?

Answer (score 0):

Try to create a new emulator using the AVD manager. If you have modified the Contact Field, etc. this could be the problem as well.